# How to summary whole column without using dataindex?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

Mostly people sum value using the gridSummary plugins.but I want to sum it using code handle by myself and put in to summaryRenderer,and my total field is add by field quantity and field lost so is a blank field.i am newbie in extjs.

Example table:

```
|-**Field quantity**-|-**Field quantity loss**-|----**Total**------|

|-------2------------|----------4----------------|-------6---------|

|-------3------------|----------5----------------|--------8--------|

|--Bottom total:---|----------9------------------|--------14-------|
```

Here is my code:

```
    { header: "Field quantity", width: 100, renderer: format2Dec, dataIndex: 'quantity', align: 'right', summaryType: 'sum' },
    { header: "Field quantity loss", width: 100, renderer: format2Dec, dataIndex: 'lost', align: 'right', summaryType: 'sum' },
    { header: "total", dataIndex: '', renderer: Cal, width: 100, align: 'right', css: 'background-color:#f2f1da !important;', summaryRenderer: total}

    function Cal(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store,total) {
              total = record.get('quantity') + record.get('lost');}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using extjs 3

try this:

```
function Cal(value, metaData, rec, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
       return rec.data.quantity + rec.data.lost;
}
```